# How to use 'bundle' instead of 'intent.putExtra()' in Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

In `Activity` I have used the following code for passing the value to other *Activity* classes:

```
intent.putExtra("book_arr", book_arr);  // [putExtra(String *name*,Serializable *Value*)]
```

How to use like this code in Android Fragments?

I have tried the following code, but it is not supporting serialized value:

```
Bundle args =new Bundle();
args.putInt("book_arr", book_arr);
```

Thanks,

Comment: `args.putSerializable("book_arr", book_arr);`

Comment: @AndyRes:Thanks..How to get the value ?

Comment: The value you'll get by using `getSerializable()` method and casting the result to the appropriate type, the type of `book_arr`. eg.: `Book[] book_arr = (Book[])args.getSerializable("book_arr");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
args.putSerializable("book_arr", book_arr);
```

If your `book_arr` (which should be `bookArr`) is a large array of heavy objects, consider making them [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). You'll need to write additional code, but it's about x10 faster. (if it's not a big object you probably shouldn't bother). This page can be helpful

http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/